# How to check who uploaded an image on Twitter using just link to the image?

Tags: twitter, images

I came across this embedded tweet but after checking for page source and all I couldn't find the Twitter profile of the person who uploaded it.How can I see who uploaded an image using Twitter?

I have tried Google reverse image search!

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it here: https://twitter.com/sisasaid/status/1009354357211422722

You can search by a photo url like this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DgHyJf_VMAMKfRG.jpg&num=50&newwindow=1&tbm=isch
```